# Sample forms with orbeon on tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, orbeon

I'm trying out the sample forms with orbeon-4.9.0.201505052329-CE running on tomcat 8.0.24.I'm getting the following exception in the logs.  javax.servlet.ServletException: configuration file exist-conf.xml not found or not readable. Any help would be great !

Comment: show code, nail down the problem, check your conf.xml, what do you expect us to do with this??

Comment: Thanks, I believe the problem is that some component cannot find the exist-conf.xml file. I'm been following the instruction here (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Installation). When I access the form builder I can create a form but cannot save it. Also when accessing the sample forms they do not display but show an error occured

Comment: It could be a corrupted WAR file? Also, did you try pointing Tomcat to the exploded WAR from `server.xml`? Are you sure Tomcat has read access to the directory? Just a few things to check.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I validated file and directory permissions across file structure. For installation I simply placed the WAR into the webs folder and Tomcat expanded it out. I did not update any Tomcat configs maybe this is where things went bad....

Comment: Maybe try unzipping by hand and adding an entry to `server.xml`, as described [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Installation-~-Tomcat#custom-context-within-serverxml).